# Use Symfony Service deep in the code, is it possible without forwarding params

Tags: php, symfony, service

I know, that I can use service in Controllers and Commands simply.

But if I have complex nested architecture like this

```
// Controller
public function testUrl()
{
     (new ProcessorA())->process();
}
// ProcessorA
public function process()
{
    (new ProcessorB())->process();
}

// a lot of nested calls of processors (A, B, C ... Z)

// ProcessorZ
public function process()
{
    (new RedisService())->call(); // <- HOW CAN I GET RedisService THERE?
}
```

My registered Service:

```
App\Service\RedisService:
    class: App\Service\RedisService
    bind:
        $host: '%env(resolve:REDIS_HOST)%'
        $port: '%env(resolve:REDIS_PORT)%'
```

App\Service\RedisService:

```
namespace App\Service;
class RedisService extends \Predis\Client
{
     public function __construct(string $host, string $port)
     {
         parent::__construct(['host' => $host, 'port' => $port], []);
     }
     public function call() { ....}
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to get the service(RedisService) in depth of code by BestPractice without forwarding?
Or I have to forward Service from Controller to ProcessorZ via constructors?

```
// Controller
public function testUrl(RedisService $redis)
{
    (new ProcessorA($redis))->process();
}

// ProcessorA
public function process()
{
    (new ProcessorB($this->redis))->process();
}

// a lot of processors

// ProcessorZ
public function process()
{
    $this->redis->call();
}
```

Comment: maybe define your processors just like a service and use dependencyinjection for the RedisService?

Comment: While writing the comment, @Domagoj beat me to it and explained it perfectly. One more thing: what you did with extending Predis\Client looks like an anti-pattern. You can read more composition over inheritance here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 2):

You can register ProcessorZ as a service (or any processor for that matter) the same way you register RedisService as a service. And just like you've bound $host and $port parameter to RedisService, you can bind RedisService to ProcessorZ class.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-parameters

In your case

```
services:
    App\Service\ProcessorZ:
        arguments:
            # this is not a string, but a reference to a service
            - '@App\Service\RedisService'
```

In your ProcessorZ.php

```
...

class ProcessorZ {
 private RedisService $redisService;


public function __construct(RedisService $redisService) {

  $this->redisService = $redisService;
}


public function process()
{
    $this->redisService->call();
}

}
```

By utilizing autowiring and autoconfiguring this process can be much simpler and faster so you might want to check that out here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

Comment: Tell me please, how can I initialize ProcessorZ in ProcessorY without param for constructor?

Comment: @Ivan The basic idea is to inject ProcessorZ into ProcessorY.  In general, avoid using the `new` operator for services. It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @Ivan From your example, every Processor class can be defined a service and benefit from dependency injection, just like you did with RedisService, the only difference being is you inject scalar parameters to $host and $port, but in the case of Processors you need to inject an instantiated service object. Symfony does the instantiation for you, you just need to tell it which service you want, either manually like explained above, or automatically - footnote at the end of the answer.